# MySQL Injection - Bypassing string filter that affect column names

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

In a CTF challenge I looked at, one can inject code into a mysql query and achieve sql injection. However, if certain strings are found in the user supplied input, the php code of the site throws an error and does not execute the query. The three strings that trigger the protection are a single quote, "username" and "password".

Unfortunately, "username" and "password" are the column names in the "user" table that holds the usernames and the corresponding passwords of the registered users. The content table has 5 columns, the user table only 3. With a "union" approach one could potentially query the "user" table. However, how can I bypass the filtering of the column names?

```
1 UNION SELECT null, username, password, null, null FROM user
=> an error is thrown as the two strings "username" and "password" are found in the user input
```

I tried some string manipulation/encoding but so far I was not able to obtain the content of the "username" and "password" columns.
Does anyone know how one can refer to them without using their names or how one can encode them so that the php code does not trigger?

**UPDATE 09.05.2021**
The "content" table has 5 columns and the "user" table only 3. Therefore, I cannot use "SELECT * FROM" as the number of columns does not match.

```
function filt_func($str, array $arr)
  {
      foreach($arr as $a) {
          if (stripos($str,$a) !== false) return true;
      }
      return false;
  }

$str_filter = array("'", 'password', 'username');
$id = $_GET['id'];
...
if(filt_func($id, $str_filter)) {

}else{
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE id = " . $_GET['id'];
  ...
}
```

Comment: What's the layout of `content` and `user`?

Comment: How about `select *`?

Comment: I updated my post. Unfortunately, the number of columns does not match in both tables.

Comment: So add a couple of null columns after the * then. Sorry I thought you'd do that automatically as you'd already tried it in your original attempt